# Reading XML data in PHP, simple

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mainXML>
    <items>
        <item category="Dekorationer" name="Flot væg" description="Meget flot væg. Passer alle stuer." price="149" />
        <item category="Fritid" name="Fodbold" description="Meget rund bold. Rørt af messi." price="600" />
    </items>
</mainXML>
```

How can i read this?

So i can make like a php loop that outputs the category, name and description for example?

I tried and started out with this:

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load( 'ex.xml' );

    $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "item" );
    foreach( $items as $item )
    {
        $categorys = $item->getElementsByTagName( "category" );
        $category = $categorys->item(0)->nodeValue;

        echo $category . " -- ";
    }
```

Comment: `category` is an attribute (not a tag). See XML. To obtain it via the `DOMElement`, use [`getAttribute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php).

Comment: @hakre thank you that worked. Please write it as an answer

Comment: Sure, I also added some example code ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`category` is an attribute (not a tag). See [XML<sup>*Wikipedia*</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML). To obtain it via the `DOMElement`, use [`getAttribute()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php):

```
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $category = $item->getAttribute('category');
    echo $category, ' -- ';
}
```

Same for `description`, just change the name of the attribute to obtain:

```
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    echo 'Category: ', $item->getAttribute("category"), "\n",
         'Description: ', $item->getAttribute("description"), ' -- ';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend PHP's [simplexml_load_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
foreach ($xml->items->item as $item) {
    echo $item['category'] . ", " . $item['name'] . ", " . $item['description'] . "\n";
}
```

UPDATED, missed the extra tag.

Comment: Good idea, poor implementation. [It doesn't work](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LYlBIT).

Comment: @nickb, Thank you for catching that.

Comment: You would have had my upvote if you wouldn't load the file again but get the `SimpleXMLElement` by using the `DOMDocument` from the question. Both can work together, see [`simplexml_import_dom`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php).

Comment: @hakre, Thanks, I didn't know you could do that. Looks like I've got some reading to do tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example using PHP's SimpleXML, specifically the [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string) function.

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mainXML>
    <items>
        <item category="Dekorationer" name="Flot væg" description="Meget flot væg. Passer alle stuer." price="149" />
        <item category="Fritid" name="Fodbold" description="Meget rund bold. Rørt af messi." price="600" />
    </items>
</mainXML>';

 $xml = simplexml_load_string( $xml);

 foreach( $xml->items[0] as $item)
 {
     $attributes = $item[0]->attributes();
     echo 'Category: ' . $attributes['category'] . ', Name: ' . $attributes['name'] . ', Description: ' . $attributes['description'];
 }
```