# Retrieving a database column that contains xml

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, xml

I must admit it is late and I am tired. Perhaps too tired to see what is in front of me! I have a MS database table where 1 column contains xml data. I need to retrieve the data into a variable (or whatever) and then display it.

I am connected to the database. I can retrieve data from any other column. However, when I execute this statement on column 1(which contains the xml):

```
$Text = sqlsrv_get_field( $results, 1);
```

I get this error: SearchPatentID(): 22872056 is not a valid stream resource...

I do NOT get this error on any other column in the table. So,

```
$Whatever = sqlsrv_get_field( $results, 3);
```

works just fine. I am not concerned about how to display the data, just how to get it so I can do what I need.

thanks in advance it is ALWAYS greatly appreciated.
Shimon

Comment: See the below link :

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482038/reading-xml-data-in-php-simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my problem.

```
$stream = sqlsrv_get_field( $results, 1, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM( SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR));
```

Then you can loop through $stream to display or do whatever you want with the data.

```
while( !feof( $stream))
{ 
    $str = fread( $stream, 10000);
    echo $str;
}
```